# MongoDB driver handle field type on insert

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation

Is there automatic type casting in MongoDB Driver like in Mongoose?

If so what does it look like? If not, how is this typically handled?
Right now I pass the payload to a function that spits out a correctly typed version of it...but I feel like there's probably a better way to do this.

I have the client sending FormData via PUT/POST requests that will be saved into a MongoDB collection, but all the fields in a FormData are strings, so I need a way to convert them according to the Schema.

Comment: Can you post your schema for illustration purposes?